# TestFlight build with error: One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, ios-frameworks

I've been recently trying to overcome the problem mentioned in the email I receive when I upload a build to TestFlight:

```
ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.
```

I have added Google Admob via Cocoapods (it's the only library I have in Cocoapods) and I have several other libraries added via SPM:

[image]

[image]

I have also tried to validate the IPA generated for which I receive the dreadful email and Xcode says that it's a valid IPA.

I have also tried looking at https://medium.com/360learning-engineering/resolving-itms-90562-invalid-bundle-email-from-the-app-store-d4a1030418e5 and the frameworks that I get with the `@rpath` are the following, but the problem I have here is that since I'm using Cocoapods and SPM, there's no Frameworks folder:

```
@rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
@rpath/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
@rpath/nanopb.framework/nanopb (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
@rpath/libswift_Concurrency.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 5.6.0, weak)
```

This is the content of the folder:

[image]

I have also tried to add those libraries with the `@rpath` to the `Link binary with libraries` but I'm still getting the email.

I'm at this point completely stuck since I don't know what else I can do here, nor how to fix this, so any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to disable bitcode